# Getter returning '0' value; not passing object?

Tags: java, getter-setter

I've just started learning Java, and I encountered a bit of a problem while writing/experimenting with a simple program.

This is the method iM that calls the getter, getDateDifference() from the class VDC.

```
 public static void iM() {

    VDC answer = new VDC();
    long theAnswer = answer.getDateDifference();
    System.out.println(theAnswer);

    }
```

Which prints out a zero.

And this is class VDC.

```
public class VDC {



public static long dateDifference;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VDC.dateDifference();
        System.out.println(dateDifference);
    }

    public static void dateDifference() throws ParseException{

        String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        Date startDate = format.parse("22/06/2017/15/00");
        System.out.println("Start Date: " + startDate);

        Date dNow = new Date();
        System.out.println("Current date is: " + dNow);
        long diff = dNow.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        dateDifference = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public long getDateDifference() {
        return dateDifference;
    }

    public void setDateDifference(long dateDifference) {
        VDC.dateDifference = dateDifference;
    }
}
```

I'm fairly certain that I wrote the setter and getter correctly, and running VDC.java in Eclipse gives me the correct value of dateDifference. However, if I attempt to run the class in which method iM is written in, dateDifference returns a value of 0.

After googling for far too long, I think my problem might be that the instance dateDifference isn't set to the passed dateDifference that originates from class VDC (Sorry if I'm confusing anyone).

I have tried to apply what I found in other SOF questions to my program, but I find myself unable to do so. How can I ensure that getDateDifference() returns the correct value (instead of 0) in another class?

(I am sorry if this is a bad question; I simply am unable to apply what I've found to solve my problem)

Comment: Where do you call the setter before calling the getter in your `iM()` method? If you never set a date difference, how would you expect it to be anything but 0 value?

Comment: Just a hint - having a field and a method with the same name can only lead to horrible confusion.  Perhaps `calculateDateDifference` would be a better name for the method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the help. Just to clarify, is it because I'm creating a new instance of the dateDifference variable and not actually using the dateDifference variable in VDC.java that I get 0 instead of the correct value?

Comment: @Dawood Thanks for the suggestion, I really didn't notice that I might have that problem in future.

Answer (score 2):

`dateDifference` is a static variable initialized by the static method `dateDifference()`.

You never call that method in your `iM()` method, so it's not initialized.

On the other hand, when you run the `main` of the `VDC` class, you call `VDC.dateDifference()` which initializes that variable.

That said, it is a bad idea to have an instance getter/setter methods that return/modify a static variable. Either make `getDateDifference()` and `setDateDifference()` static methods, or make `dateDifference` a non-static variable.

Here's one possible implementation that could make sense:

```
public static void iM() {
    VDC answer = new VDC();
    answer.computeDateDifference(); // initialize the instance variable
    long theAnswer = answer.setDateDifference(); // get its value
    System.out.println(theAnswer);
}

public class VDC {

    private long dateDifference;

    public void computeDateDifference() throws ParseException {

        String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        Date startDate = format.parse("22/06/2017/15/00");
        System.out.println("Start Date: " + startDate);

        Date dNow = new Date();
        System.out.println("Current date is: " + dNow);
        long diff = dNow.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        this.dateDifference = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public long getDateDifference() {
        return dateDifference;
    }

    public void setDateDifference(long dateDifference) {
        this.dateDifference = dateDifference;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never invoke neither `setDateDifference` nor `dateDifference`.
So you need to change your `iM` to

```
public static void iM() {
    try {
        VDC.dateDifference();
        long theAnswer = answer.getDateDifference();
        System.out.println(theAnswer);
    catch (ParseException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since your methods are static you do not need to create an instance of `VDC`.